# Are these statements true or false

Tags: calculus

Let $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f$ a function from $A$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$.

1. If $f$ is not bounded, then there exist $x\in A$ where $f$ tends to infinity.
2. If the limit of $f$ doesn't exist in $x\in A$, then $f$ is not bounded

---

1.FALSE we can take $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$ .$f$ is not bounded and it doesn't exist $x\in A$ such that $f$ tends to infinity.

2.FALSE we can take $f:\{1\}\cup (2,3) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that $f(x)=x$ . The limit doesn't exist for $x=1$ and $f$ is bounded

---

IS IT CORRECT?

Comment: "then there exist $x\in A$ such that $f$ tends to infinity." Somehow, this sentence should incorporate $x$ in the part after "such".//// For your second example: Why does the "limit for $x=1$" not exist?

Comment: @Babelfish because $x=1$ it is not a ?limit point? (punto de acumulacion in spanish) https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punto_de_acumulaci%C3%B3n. And the definition of limit in a point requires that that point is a limit point

Comment: You need to state the questions more clearly.  What is $x$ in 1?  If it is just one point, how can $f(x)$ tend to infinity?  It would be more normal to ask if there is a sequence of points $x_i$ so that $f(x_i)$ tends to infinity.  For 2, if the limit of $f$ as what?

Comment: @user586431 Can you make precise what "a limit exists in $x$" and "a limit in $x$ does not exist" means? If yes, feel free to add it to your question. And I think you also want to give your question a more meaningful title. There are also some more tags you could use.

Comment: The first one is fine. The second is indeed false, but whether your example works is probably a matter of convention. Try to prove something more interesting, namely that there is $A$ and a point $a\in A$ limit of points of $A$, and a function on $A$ bounded but such that its limit at $a$ does not exist.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo like this $f:(0,2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ where $f(x)=1 $ if  $0<x<=1$  and $f(x)=2$ if $1<x<2$. It doesnt exist limit in $x=1$ and f is bounded

Comment: Yes, that's a good example. You can also find examples for the first question where the function is defined on a bounded interval, and even on a closed bounded interval.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo okay. Thank you!